# Dividing SUM By A Distinct Count and getting an error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting an ORA-00937 (not a single-group group by function) on the below query. Any ideas please?The query is simply dividing a SUM by a Count.

```
SELECT sum(DISTINCT CE.USD_NOTIONAL)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MARKET_DATE) FROM DATA_EURO_YTD WHERE MARKET_DATE >= TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))  
FROM CE
WHERE CE.tradedate >= '01-JAN-2019'
AND CE.exchange IN (SELECT DISTINCT EXCHANGE FROM exchange EX
WHERE EX.FEED IN ('Y'))
```

Comment: That's many `DISTINCT`. What is the reason behind that? What do the tables actually contain? What are their keys? The query can probably written much simpler, but we need more Information in order to give good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the subquery to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT CE.USD_NOTIONAL) / MAX(dey.cntd)
FROM CE CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT MARKET_DATE) as cntd
      FROM DATA_EURO_YTD
      WHERE MARKET_DATE >= DATE '2019-01-01'
     )   dey
WHERE CE.tradedate >= DATE '2019-01-01'  AND
      CE.exchange IN (SELECT EXCHANGE
                      FROM exchange EX
                      WHERE EX.FEED IN ('Y')
                     );
```

Notes:

- Moving the subquery to the `FROM` clause almost solves the whole problem.  You still need an aggregation around the value.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant in an `IN` subquery.
- I fixed the dates to use the `DATE` prefix for date literals.

Comment: Sorry unclear as to why my subquery was not working. Can you please shed some light on that so that I understand better.

Comment: In the subuery I am getting a count, essentially one value. So not sure how the MAX is sorting out the issue or moving the subquery to FROM?

Comment: @AM_86 . . . It is not allowed with `GROUP BY`.  All expressions in the `SELECT` of an aggregation query need to be aggregation keys or arguments to aggregation functions.  Although your `GROUP BY` might technically qualify, it is hard for the SQL engine to figure that out.